# MySQL Fastest Way To Handle Composite Key Query

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

I'm having some issues with slow queries on a MySQL database with many rows and I'm just hoping to make sure I'm doing this right.

I have a table that contains a TAID with an associated Row like this:

```
Row | TAID
----------
 1      1
 2      1
 3      1
 4      1
 1      2
 2      2
 3      2
 4      2
```

Currently I have `TAID, Row` setup as a Composite Key, but I generally query all the rows using the TAID column.

Is it slow because there are multiple instances of the TAID?

Am I thinking about this the right way?

**Edit:** I think the order of the columns is the problem.

I actually have the Row before the TAID and I'm querying on the TAID.

Going to try flipping the order.

Comment: Note that, by convention, we wouldn't normally call such a column 'id'

Comment: It's actually called TAID, but I was just using it as an example.

Comment: Is it necessary to add an ID column that just contains an ID?

Comment: No. And note that an edit button is provided

Comment: Any prefix of a composite index is also an effective index by itself.

Comment: I edited the question to show TAID and I'm grabbing the column config rq. Thanks Barmar, that's what I thought

Comment: So searching by `TAID` should be fast.

Comment: I think I see the problem - the RowNumber is actually the column before the ID

Comment: So I'm guessing that the ID isn't indexed properly

Comment: Is it possible to flip the order?

Comment: Use `ALTER INDEX` to change the order in the index.

Comment: Per this I think I have to drop the index and re-create. `There is no ALTER INDEX command in MySQL. You can only DROP INDEX and then CREATE INDEX with the new name.`

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name:

Answer (score 1):

As suggested the order of the Composite keys needed to be flipped.

Since I'm querying on the TAID, it needs to be the first key.